# Does traffic leave GCP when using the public APIs?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

For example let's say I have service A and B in GCP. Imagine that we are sending data from a VM in GCP to CloudStorage.

A sends B 10GB of traffic using the public API. In GCP would this this result in the data exiting the GCP network and then coming back in or would the entire exchange of data stay local to the GCP network?

Comment: You could try running a `traceroute` to see what happens (assuming you know the hostnames/ip addresses)

Answer (score 0):

Google VPC provides private communication between compute resources you create, and you can also enable private communication to Google managed services like Google Cloud Storage, Spanner, big data and analytics, and Machine Learning

For more details see here - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/private-google-access/private-google-access

Comment: but what about service to service traffic or traffic without vpc endpoints? For example if pubsub asks for traffic from cloudstorage what happens to the traffic, does it ever breach the network and go into the public net?

not all services have public endpoints and wont have for a while

Answer (score 0):

The traffic is all internal and private though the API is resolved to a public destination IP address. Network address translation is in Google's infrastructure and is transparent to the user.